# "Он что, тебе не поверил?" Как объяснить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Он что, тебе не поверил?** Хотелось бы получить объяснение, почему в этом и подобных ему случаях после **что** ставится запятая.

Comment: Не могу представить, как можно подумать, что тут можно без запятой.) Другое дело не понимать почему. Но совсем не обиду Вам пусть будет, Матвей, просто удивился.

Comment: Честно говоря, я и не думал, что здесь можно без запятой.) Меня интересовало именно то, почему здесь ставится запятая. Просто вопрос неудачно мной задан.

Comment: Я переформулировал вопрос, Артём.

Comment: Отлично, что не думали.) Может, "?" в конце не нужен? Это, конечно, спорный вопрос, но вроде тут нет сильной вопросительной интонации. Или есть? Простите, что обращаю внимание на мелочи, просто подумал, может, так лучше будет.

Comment: Не нужен. Он от предыдущего вопроса остался.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, нужна.

2. Запятыми отделяются слова **что, что ж, что же, как же,** выражающие вопрос, подтверждение, восклицание, например:
   Что, если я кликну клич? (Тургенев) (в значении «что будет, если...»);
   Что ж, я готов (в значении «да, приходится согласиться»);
   Как же, мы все уже приготовили (в значении «конечно, разумеется»);
   Как же, поможет он тебе в беде! (в значении выражения несогласия, отказа).

Но:
Что она, глухая или глухонемая, эта девочка? (вопрос заключен в словах *что она*, образующих предложение: *что она* в значении «какова она»).
Что же мне, хвалить их за это? (*что же мне* – неполное предложение в значении «что же мне делать»).

[XXVI. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ ПРИ СЛОВАХ, ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИ НЕ СВЯЗАННЫХ С ЧЛЕНАМИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm)